# Expander in wpf with icon button

Tags: wpf, prism, wpf-4.0

I have expander in wpf. I need Expander with header icon(as Notes icon) on right side without change the expander icon. From that i have to drag and drop on chart lines and make it as a small notes.

Comment: How to drag and drop the button in wpf

Answer (score 1):

Try using and changing the controltemplate for the default expander. You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You use the template found on the website and put your Notes icon somewhere in between (in the header section). Just play around with it and you will find that it is rather easy to customize it. Have fun!